# object seems to be too bright?

Tags: rendering

the eyes for the character im making stand out rediculously because its as if theyre emmitting light. it could be something obvious that im unaware of, perhaps its the image texture for the eye itself? i dont think its the lights because as you can see the rest of the textures look fine and i tried rendering with just the sun light and i still get the same problem. i had to include a .blend file of only the eyeballs because it wouldnt let me include the original file since it was too big :(
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you perhaps have a viewer node active inside your materials?

Comment: For future reference, when asking questions about materials, please include an image of your material node tree as well as the file (when including a file). This way, there is more information that is immediately accessible to other readers that are able to help. Thanks.

Comment: no there isnt a viewer node just the simple material and output